# Vuejs: Parent component not updating after updating child component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I need clarity. When there is update in a child component in vuejs, even the parent also triggers its updated hook. But I thought that the parent had already undergone updates in its data, go to update and perhaps resume the initial values, but nothing happens. Does anyone have any idea of this behavior.

Comment: could be something to do with your code ...

Comment: Updates in children do not propagate to the parent - only updates in parent may eventually propagate to 1 or more children.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you are looking for something like custom events.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html